# How to copy first pattern just before searched pattern from shell command output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

I've got output from shell command like this:

```
theme get --list -p=$PASS -s=$STORE
```

Output:

```
Available theme versions:

[10462576304] Debut

[134241503419] 1.0.4

[32602837511] 1.0.5

[223235633345] [live] test
```

I want to export to variable number between `[ ]` before match `[live]` f.e `223235633345`.

The pattern `[live]` not always can be at the last line, but I want the only id(number) just for first before [live]

I started from something like this:

```
v=`theme get --list -p=$PASS -s=$STORE | grep '[live]'
```

Comment: please show your attempted code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
theme get --list -p=$PASS -s="$STORE" |
awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) if ($(i+1) == "[live]") {gsub(/[][]/, "", $i); print $i; exit}}'

223235633345
```

Comment: Thank You very much anubhava! It really helps me to solve my issue. I have to make little corrections to work but it great!!           theme get --list -p=$PASS -s="$STORE" | awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) if(index($i,"[live]")) {gsub(/[][live]/, "", $i); print $i;}}'